# Add and access binary blob raw data file to iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, blob

How do I add a binary/blob *file* with some binary data (not executable, not image, not audio, just raw binary data) to an iOS project and then access it within the application as a `Data` or `uint8` array?

I tried to search terms: embedded binary (got only answers about executables), embedded blob (but only found answers about SQLite blobs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the file to your project structure (first tab of the left panel) using drag and drop or using right-click on a folder -> "Add files to ..."

The file should automatically be embedded into your app after that. You can check by going to your project settings (click on the first blue icon in the project structure), then under TARGETS, select your app and go to the "Build Phases" tab. There you should see a "Copy Bundle Resources" phase. Make sure your file is part of it and if not, add it with the + button.

Then inside your app it's really simple. If your file is named `foo.xyz`, then do

```
func loadFile() -> Data?
{
    guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "foo", withExtension: "xyz") else {
        print("Failed to create URL for file.")
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        return data
    }
    catch {
        print("Error opening file: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: The file *must* be present, otherwise the application is not built correctly. So passing `nil` to the caller makes no sense, it only would hide a *programming error.* (What would you display to the user in that case? *"Data not found, wait for an app update"*?) – This is a situation  where force-unwrap/force-try is acceptable, and helps to find programming errors early.

Comment: @MartinR I agree, but you can always force unwrap the result of the function if that's the behavior you want. It gives you the benefit of having a print of the error in the console. Beginners tend to force unwrap everything when most of the time they shouldn't, so I try not to encourage this behaviour in my examples on SO. Also I personally never force unwrap, I use errors in the console which help me catch bugs just as easily during debug and are safer for prod (but that's just my style, not necessarily a best practice).

Comment: Also a message saying *I'm a crappy developer, my app is not built correctly* is better than a crash in my opinion, but again, that's just me :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the file is simple - just right click on the group you want to add it into, choose `Add files to xxx` and choose your file. Make sure that your app's target is selected (it probably will be by default) so it gets added to that bundle.

Accessing that binary file is pretty simple too:

```
guard
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Filename", withExtension: "bin")
    let data = Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        print("Well, that didn't work")
}

print("Look - data: \(data)")
```